# OCaml - Compile OCaml and C code that uses Ctypes

Tags: c, ocaml, interfacing

I'm trying to learn how to call routines in C directly from OCaml code, using the `Ctypes` library.

I have this basic example with two files: `hello.ml` and `hello.c`.

`hello.ml` looks like this:

```
open Ctypes
open Foreign

let hello = 
    foreign "hello" (float @ -> returning void)
;;

let () = 
    hello 3.15
;;
```

`hello.c` looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(double x)
{
    if ( x > 0)
        printf("hello!\n");
}
```

How do I compile these two files into one executable?

The process of manually compiling/linking code is scary to me and I don't understand it very well. I usually use a Makefile template to compile my code because that's really easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that I use on OS X.

in simple.c

```
int adder(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

and in simple.ml

```
open Ctypes
open Foreign
let adder_ = foreign
    "adder" (int @-> int @-> returning int)

let () =
  print_endline (string_of_int (adder_ 1 2))
```

Then I do

```
clang -shared simple.c -o simple.so 
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package ctypes.foreign -cclib simple.so -linkpkg simple.ml -o Test
./Test
```

And that should print out 3 on the terminal.